# Regex to include some files but with one exception

Tags: regex

I would like a regex that includes all filenames with a certain ending ex. ".err" but not if this filename starts with e.g. "test". In other words include "*.err"-files but not "test-whatever.err"-files.

I have found that

```
    (?!test.*\.err$).*\.err
```

excludes the test*.err files and that

```
    .*\.err
```

includes all the *.err files, but I need them both in the same expression.

Also the fact that the ".err" can be written as ".ERR" or ".Err" must be taken into concideration for this regex to work properly for me.

All thoughts and ideas are appreciated!

Regards
Rickard

Comment: You must specify the language you are using the regex from. It's even written in the Regex tag description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```
^(?i)(?!test).*\.err$
```

See it here [online on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2us8q)

The important parts, that are different to yours:

Use anchors. `^` and `$` are anchoring your pattern to the start and to the end of the string

`(?i)` makes it "ignorecase", so that `err` will also match "ERR" or "ErR" and `test` will also match "Test" and TEST ...

You didn't gave the language, but this features should work with the most flavours.

Answer (score 0):

How about this one:

```
^(?!test).*\.err$
```